# What is the equivalent Query Builder expression with 2 table selects in laravel

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I have the following sql query,

```
select products.*
from orders,
    json_table(
      orders.order_summary,
      "$.products[*]"
      columns(
        quantity int path "$.quantity",
        variant_id int path "$.variant_id"
      )
) products
```

Since this involves 2 table names even though its an alias for a part of the JSON column in the same table, I am not able to figure out an equivalent query builder syntax.

```
DB::table('orders,  json_table(
      orders.order_summary,
      "$.products[*]"
      columns(
        quantity int path "$.quantity",
        variant_id int path "$.variant_id"
      )
    ) products')->select('variant_id','quantity')
```

when I try to do the above statement, eloquent applies quotes around "`$`.`quantity`"

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using very specific MySQL json functions, Eloquent has not methods for all of them, so in this case maybe the best way will be:

```
$data = Order::selectRaw("json_table(orders.order_summary, 
                            '$.products[*]' columns( quantity int path '$.quantity',
                        variant_id int path '$.variant_id'")->get();
```

- Invoke the `Order` model
- Use `selectRaw` to process complex or pure SQL queries
- Use double quotes to the main query and single quotes to variables
- Use at the end `get` to fetch all data from your query

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, But actually this doesn't work for me. The output of the above query looks like this ```select orders, json_table(orders.order_summary, 
                            '$.products[*]' columns( quantity int path '$.quantity',
                        variant_id int path '$.variant_id' from `orders``` As you can see this is not exactly I wanted. Eloquent treats whatever inside the `selectRaw()` as a column, in our case that should be a table name

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar need!

### Issue

The other answer seemed to think it was an issue of comma separating **selects** with RAW statements - but it is not -  **we need a way to comma separate the `from`**

```
select <field> from <table>, <JSON_TABLE>
```

### My Solution

In my situation, I am using a `fromSub($query, $alias)` where I was able to use the `$alias` for my `DB::raw` statement with the `JSON_TABLE`. eg. `fromSub($query, DB::raw('alias, JSON_TABLE(...))` - notice the `alias` is still at the beginning!

See below:

##### Raw Query

```
-- customers: content editors!
select id
from (
select
    owner_id as account_id,
    JSON_EXTRACT(value, '$[*].value') AS allowed_users
from configuration_values cv inner join configurations c on c.id = cv.configuration_id and c.`key` = 'content_editors'
) ace, JSON_TABLE(ace.allowed_users, '$[*]' COLUMNS(id INT PATH '$')) as j
```

##### DB:: query builder

```
$ace = DB::table('configuration_values as cv')
    ->select('owner_id as account_id', DB::raw('JSON_EXTRACT(value, "$[*].value") AS allowed_users'))
    ->join('configurations as c', function($q){
        $q->on('c.id', '=', 'cv.configuration_id')
            ->where('c.key', 'content_editors');
    });

 $ce = DB::query()
    ->select('id')
    ->fromSub(
        $ace, 
         DB::raw('ace, JSON_TABLE(ace.allowed_users, "$[*]" COLUMNS(id INT PATH "$")) as j')
    );

return $ce->get();
```

---

#### FOR OP

I believe you can use the `table($name, $alias)` with `DB::raw(`

```
DB::table('orders,  DB::raw(json_table(
      orders.order_summary,
      "$.products[*]"
      columns(
        quantity int path "$.quantity",
        variant_id int path "$.variant_id"
      )
    ) products'))->select('variant_id','quantity')
```